# Question on Continuous function and Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

$f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is contiuous. If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) < C$ ($C$ is constant).

Prove that there is $r>0$ such that $\forall{y} \in B_r (x)$, $f(y)<C$

---

f is continuous and a linear map, so its a Lipschitz

so $||f(x)-f(y)|| \leq C||x-y||$ for all $x,y \in S$

if $r = \frac{\xi}{C}$ and $\xi > 0$

then $||f(x)-f(y)|| \leq C||x-y|| \le Cr =\xi$

which I dont know how it can relate to $\forall{y} \in B_r (x)$ and smaller than $C$

Comment: So $f$ is linear? You did not say that. And anyway you do not need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

Since $(-\infty,C)$ is open and $f$ is continuous, 
$$
U=\{y\;;\; f(y)<C\}
$$
is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now take $x$ in $U$. Since $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, there exists $r>0$ such that
$$
x\in B_r(x)\subseteq U.
$$

This is because the open balls $B_r(x)$ constitute a neighborhood basis for $x$.

**Approach 2**

With $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity between metric spaces.

Take $$\epsilon=(C-f(x))/2>0.$$

By continuity at $x$, there exists $r>0$ such that
$$
f(x)-\epsilon<f(y)<f(x)+\epsilon=\frac{C+f(x)}{2}<C
$$
for all $\|x-y\|<r$.

Comment: why $(-\infty, C)$ is open and continuous can make $f(y)<C$???

Comment: @Paul It is $B(r(x)\subseteq U$ that makes $f(y)<C$ for all $y\in B_r(x)$. If you don't follow the first approach for now, just do approach 2. Is it ok for this one?

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain what I can do to improve this answer?

Comment: approach2 is easier to understand. Thanks!!